# ConnectionRefused upon copying a txt file to hdfs

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, connection, hdfs

When I try to copy my input file named "input.txt" to hdfs like,

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/pras/input/input.txt /pras
```

I get the following exception.

```
put: Call From pras-Insp/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection 
exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: There might be an authentication issue, usually you have a dedicated user (hduser) to interact with hadoop. You could check the permission in your hdfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried `$ jps` I did not see a namenode. So,

1) I stopped the hadoop service

```
$ ./stop-all.sh
```

2) Formated the namenode.

```
$ hdfs namenode -format
```

3) Restarted it again.

```
$ ./start-all.sh
```

Now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you mentioned HDFS directory path where you want to put the input.txt file. ?

It should be like hadoop fs -put /home/user/input.txt /tmp (/tmp is HDFS directory).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the core-site.xml is not configured well.Go to $HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop , edit the core-site.xml and set the property below:

```
    <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
```

For more help, check this out

http://codesfusion.blogspot.gr/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html